# Exposing complex C++ Qt object to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-cascades

In a C++ file, I have an object of the type `QList<QStringList>*`, which is supposed to be a two dimensional String array.

Currently, in C++ I am able to do this:

```
// this will display the QString value in the Console,
// where entries is of type QList<QStringList>*
qDebug() << "test: " << entries->at(0).at(0);
```

I know how to expose this object to QML, but how am I going to be able to navigate / access its functions in QML ?

In `main.qml`, I can call the function that returns this object:

```
_app.getCalendar()
```

But how can I navigate it, like in the C++ code, above?

EDIT: What I actually need to do, is send a two dimensional String array from C++ to QML. Am I doing this in an overly complicated way? Is there another way of accomplishing this?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?  Is there a question here?

Comment: My question is: how can I navigate in this two dimensional array, in QML?

Comment: Could [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287252/accessing-c-qlists-from-qml) answers help you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define an `INVOKABLE` getter function in the class you exposed to QML.

header:

```
class MyQmlClass : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // ...

    Q_INVOKABLE QString getString(int y, int y);


    // ...
}
```

and implement it in the .cpp file ad follows:

```
QString MyQmlClass::getString(int x, int y)
{
    return entries->at(x).at(y);
}
```

Finally in QML:

```
_app.getCalendar().getString(3, 4)
```