# trying to access QList of struct members in qml

Tags: c++, qt, struct, qml

I need to know how to acess the members of struct from qlist in qml.

Currently i can acess only the members of struct in qml and i am also able to acess simple qlist i.e. Qlist made of qString.

**But the problem starts when i try to acess the members of struct embedded in qlist.**

I have created a struct (MyStruct) in c++ and can acscess it in Qml. I can also acess QList ( which is QStrinList).

But **problem comes when i am trying to access QList**. it gives me the error

```
qrc:/OrderBar.qml:26: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name1' of undefined
```

the Codes are

QML

```
    Text{
        //text: myModel2.mystr.name1  // this works
        text: myModel2.lstr[0].name1
        y: sensor.width + 5
        font.family: "Helvetica"
        font.pointSize: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
```

C++

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QObject>

struct MyStruct {
    Q_GADGET
   // Q_OBJECT
    int m_val;

public:
    QString m_name1;
    QString m_name2;
    QString m_name3;
    QString m_name4;
    Q_PROPERTY(int val MEMBER m_val)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name1 MEMBER m_name1)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name2 MEMBER m_name2)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name3 MEMBER m_name3)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name4 MEMBER m_name4)
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyStruct);

class test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MyStruct mystr READ getMyStruct
               WRITE setMyStruct NOTIFY myStructChanged)

    Q_PROPERTY(QList<MyStruct> lstr READ getLstr
               WRITE setLstr NOTIFY lstrChanged)

public:
    explicit test(QObject *parent = nullptr);


    MyStruct strObj;

    MyStruct getMyStruct() const
    {
        return strObj;
    }


    void setMyStruct(MyStruct val)
    {
        strObj = val;
        emit myStructChanged();
    }

    QList<MyStruct> strList;

    QList<MyStruct>  getLstr() const
    {
        return strList;
    }

    void setLstr(QList<MyStruct> val)
    {
        strList = val;
        emit lstrChanged();
    }



signals:
    void myStructChanged();
    void lstrChanged();

public slots:

};

#endif // TEST_H
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

test::test(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    MyStruct l_value;
    l_value.m_name1 = "b1";
    l_value.m_name2 = "b2";

    setMyStruct(l_value);


     QList<MyStruct> l_strList;

     l_strList.append(l_value);

     setLstr(l_strList);

}
```

Comment: Perhaps this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287252/accessing-c-qlists-from-qml) is helpful, especially the answer from theBooTroo?

Comment: @Amfasis I think you're pointing the OP in the wrong direction, since `MyStruct` is a  `Q_GADGET`, which is not even mentioned in the post you linked.

Comment: I'm aware that it's not a gadget in the other post, I was more thinking in the direction of making it a pointer. But agreed, that was not clear from my comment

Answer (score 0):

The codes are absolutely right. I found out that this is a bug in Qt older version. I tested the codes with QT 5.14 and it fully works.