# Advice to importing a list with instances of a class from c++ to qml in runtime

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QList where each element is a instance of a c++ class. These instances contain information and based on that I want to create and move rectangles in QML. The contained information is the x position (among other things) and I want to create/move one rectangle per element in the QList. The QList gets updated in periodic intervals in runtime, meaning some elements can get added, removed or the x position edited.

I programmed a small example to understand how to accomplish the bridge between c++ and QML, but I think my code will only work once as a initialization and not if I update the QList in runtime. Am I on the right track and if not, what do I have to change? Is it necessary to use QAbstractListModel like suggested in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287252/accessing-c-qlists-from-qml) question by Timmmm?

Here's my code:
class.h:

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

#include <QQuickItem>

class RectangelClass : public QObject
{
private:
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int xPos READ xPos WRITE setXPos NOTIFY xPosChanged)
    int m_xPos;

public:
    RectangelClass () {}
    int xPos() const { return m_xPos; }

public slots:
    void setXPos(int arg)
    {
        if (m_xPos == arg)
            return;

        m_xPos = arg;
        emit xPosChanged(arg);
    }

signals:
    void xPosChanged(int arg);
};

class RectangelClassManager : public QObject
{
private:
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList <QObject*> rectangelClassList READ rectangelClassList WRITE setRectangelClassList NOTIFY rectangelClassListChanged)
    QList <QObject*> m_rectangelClassList;

public:
    RectangelClassManager ()
    {
        QList <QObject*> localObjList;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            RectangelClass *localObj = new RectangelClass();
            localObj->setXPos (i*100);
            localObjList.push_back(localObj);
        }

        setRectangelClassList (localObjList);

    }

    QList <QObject*> rectangelClassList () const { return m_rectangelClassList; }

public slots:
    void setRectangelClassList (QList <QObject*> arg)
    {
        if (m_rectangelClassList == arg)
            return;

        m_rectangelClassList = arg;
        emit rectangelClassListChanged(arg);
    }

signals:
    void rectangelClassListChanged (QList <QObject*> arg);
};

#endif // CLASS_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "class.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<RectangelClass>("cppclasses", 1, 0, "RectangelClass");
    qmlRegisterType<RectangelClassManager>("cppclasses", 1, 0, "RectangelClassManager");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import cppclasses 1.0


Window {

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    RectangelClassManager{
        id: rectangelClassManager
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: rect0
        x: rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList[0].xPos
        y: 100
        width: 80
        height: 80
        color:"yellow"
        Text {
            id: textid0
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "X-Position: " + rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList[0].xPos
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: rect1
        x: rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList[1].xPos
        y: 100
        width: 80
        height: 80
        color:"yellow"
        Text {
            id: textid1
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "X-Position: " + rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList[1].xPos
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: rect2
        x: rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList[2].xPos
        y: 100
        width: 80
        height: 80
        color:"yellow"
        Text {
            id: textid2
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "X-Position: " + rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList[2].xPos
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: rect3
        x: rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList[3].xPos
        y: 100
        width: 80
        height: 80
        color:"yellow"
        Text {
            id: textid3
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "X-Position: " + rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList[3].xPos
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: rect4
        x: rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList[4].xPos
        y: 100
        width: 80
        height: 80
        color:"yellow"
        Text {
            id: textid4
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "X-Position: " + rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList[4].xPos
        }
    }
}
```

Edit to make my question more clear:
Is it possible to update the QList in runtime in c++, will it be updated in QML and if not, how do I achieve that instead.

Comment: I suggest editing this post. What is your specific problem? What are you having trouble with? Too much ambiguity in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a `QList` property can be updated in runtime by emitting the `rectangelClassListChanged()` signal. However, this can be very ineffecient, since the whole list is reparsed. So, depending on how often your `QList` changes, you might be better of changing it to a `QAbstractListModel`.

Also, you can change your code to use a `Repeater`, it hurts my programmer-eyes ;-) and it might actually be the cause of not updating runtime.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import cppclasses 1.0


Window {

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    RectangelClassManager{
        id: rectangelClassManager
    }

    Repeater {
        model: rectangelClassManager.rectangelClassList

        delegate: Rectangle {
            x: modelData.xPos
            y: 100
            width: 80
            height: 80
            color:"yellow"
            Text {
                id: textid0
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "X-Position: " + modelData.xPos
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'll keep the inefficiency in mind and I used the Repeater instead.   
One thing I still do not understand is, how to update the `QList` in the `main.cpp` though. I can not call the `setRectangelClassList()` method without creating a object of the class, but if I do that, nothing changes in QML. I basically want something like this in the `main.cpp`: 
`Sleep(2000);
setRectangelClassList(newObjList);`

Comment: @Vipr0 please look on SO/Google/[Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html) about setting properties on the rootContext (can't properly answer at the moment, using smartphone)